# Combining multiple CSVs in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple csv files (which I've moved into pandas dataframes) in a folder, each of which holds monthly website data

```
January.csv:
URL    Value
page1   10
page2   52
page3   17

February.csv:
URL     Value
page1   20
page2   7
page3   15

March.csv:
URL     Value
page1   7
page2   15
page3   23
```

and need to combine them by copying the Value column from each to make a new dataframe (which will ultimately be exported to another csv)

```
URL     January   February   March
page1    10        20          7
page2    52         7         15
page3    17        15         23
```

A new csv file will be added to the folder each month, so I need to keep it as dynamic as possible. I'm currently using
`all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format('csv'))]` to get the files with the hope that I can then use something like `pd.read_csv(f)['URL'] for f in all_filenames`, but that may be totally the wrong approach?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While @robinood's answer is correct, I think it's more efficient to use generator expression (in round brackets):

```py
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format('csv'))]
result = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, index_col='URL', usecols=['URL', 'Value']) for f in all_filenames), axis=1)
```

Note that the above snippet also sets `URL` as index to avoid potential concat errors due to different sorting of the rows.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to specify which columns to include too? My source CSVs actually have a load of other columns that I'm not interested in - I only want the 'Value' column from each.

Comment: @Dave: sure, see the updated answer (added `usecols` kwarg).

Comment: That's brilliant - this has got me very close to where I need to be. Thanks so much! I had to put usecols=['URL','Value'] as it wouldn't let me use that as the index_col otherwise.

Comment: @Dave: oops, fixed the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

The start of you approach is good, with the glob and read_csv functions.

```
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format('csv'))]
all_df = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames]
```

Then when you have the list containing your dfs, you can concat them.

```
result = pd.concat(all_df, axis=1)
```

It is more efficient to read all the dataframes first, and then use once the concatenation function than concatenating each df separately.